# c# itemCommand goes to aspx.vb

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, itemcommand

just got a really nub question, I am in the process of following a tutorial on how to make a shopping cart demo with c#, for some reason when i double click on the 'itemCommand' on the events tab in the properties instead of getting normal code behind i get a weird aspx.vb page which does not look anything look anything like the tutorial

any reason for this ? and how to get the right page? maybe something i have done wrong?

Comment: Just check the top page on aspx CodeFile

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you created a VB project instead of a C# project. C# files end in .cs.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Page Directive on the Top of Aspx page

**Sample**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```